# Will commits in git and mercurial repositories with the same history have the same hash?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

When using git to clone an hg repository, or when migrating from hg to git, will the hashes remain the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspection, the answer appears to be "no".

`hg clone ssh://some.server.com/path/hgproject/`

`git clone hg::ssh://some.server.com/path/hgproject/`

Followed by:

`hg log -l 5`

`git log -n 5`

Show different commit hashes for the same commits.

While both git and hg use SHA-1 hashes, there must be a difference in what they are hashing, perhaps the metadata.

Any tooling dependent on the hashes will require history rewriting for a migration.

### More in depth context

Per comment by @ngoldbaum & https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Nodeid:

```
nodeid = sha1( min(parent1, parent2) + max(parent1, parent2) + contents )
```

Whereas git [computes it as](https://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html#introducing-sha-1):

```
sha1(
    meta data
        commit message
        committer
        commit date
        author
        authoring date
    hash-of-tree-object (effectively the working directory)
)
```

### Mapping

if using `git-remote-hg` to do the view or conversion you can find enough information to create a mapping in `.git/hg/origin/marks-{hg,git}`

Comment: That's right: Mercurial hashes commits, but commits contain very different data from Git commits. Mercurial does not hash files' contents and there is no concept of a *tree* or *blob* object; commits store their branch name (well, actually an index) and are therefore permanently attached *to* that branch; and commits have a local sequential index number, in Mercurial.

Comment: Mercurial does hash file contents, according to the formula on this page: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Nodeid